# Why is second level cache not being used for a particular entity?

Tags: nhibernate

I am running NHibernate Profiler and I can't work out why some entities are being retrieved from the second level cache and some are not.

I have setup all the necessary things - 2nd level cache is enabled (SysCache2), and caching is set to ReadOnly for the entities that are giving me problems. I am using transactions everywhere.

Firstly, my entities look like this:

```
Employee { Id, Name, CurrentOffice }

Office { Id, Name }

Team { Id, Name, Office }
```

Secondly, here are some example from the NH profiler to demonstrate the problem:

**Session #1**

The profile shows the following SQL call. This is generated by a Session.Get() call:

> SELECT office_.Id, office_.Name FROM Office
> office_ WHERE office_.Id = 5

**Session #2**

In session 2, an employee is loaded, which then causes an eager select on his current office. The second level cache is correctly used, as the office was cached in Session #1:

> SELECT *employee*.Id, employee_.Name, employee_.CurrentOfficeId FROM Employee
> employee_ WHERE employee_.Id = 1
>
> 2nd level cache load Office (5 /* id
> */)

**Session #3**

Next some Teams are loaded, which cause eager selects on their associated office. But now the 2nd level cache is not used for the office that we should have cached in the previous session.

> SELECT team_.Id, team_.Name, team_.OfficeId FROM Team team_ WHERE team_.Id in (7,8,9)
>
> SELECT office_.Id, office_.Name FROM Office
> office_ WHERE office_.Id = 5

Why does that the last SQL statement in Session #3 occur - why is the 2nd level cache not used, like it was in Session #2?

Comment: Can you also provide the mappings you use for your entities? Is it possible that the Office is removed from cache before your 3rd session  due to cache expiration or due to low memory? Also the version of NHibernate might be helpful for reproducing the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is running on my local computer so there's plenty of memory. I'm using NH 2.1. The cache expiration is set to 20 minutes - I've verified this in NHibernate's logs. The mappings are done with Fluent NHibernate and there's nothing special about them. The mappings include calls to Cache.ReadOnly or Cache.NonStrictWrite.

Answer (score 3):

I've worked this out.

Within the code base a call was being made that used Session.CreateSqlQuery().ExecuteUpdate().

However, the query that it was executing had no entity specified. When this happens it appears that NHibernate decides to clear all cache regions, wiping out the entire cache!

Moral of the story, don't use Session.CreateSqlQuery().ExecuteUpdate() without specifying an entity.

Comment: Can you specifiy an entity when using ExecuteUpdate()?  My understanding is that you use ExecuteUpdate() for batches where you specifically do not want the cache updated.  I would be very interested in seeing how you maintain persistence when using the ExecueUpdate() method.

Comment: You may be thinking of the 1st level cache. Actually I have no idea - my answer here was based on the limited amount of understanding I could get from tracing through the NHibernate source with the debugger. All I know is that when the query was executed my entire 2nd-level cache was wiped out. I changed the query to run using a raw ADO.NET command and it behaves much better now. I'll try and work out what is actually going on and update my answer with something more official.